# Why spark needs hadoop libraries in local or standalone mode?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I downloaded **spark-2.4.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz** package and installed in my system. I would like to run simple apache spark code in local mode, but it gives me **NoClassDefFoundError**.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
```

After googling, I found SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH is need to set to hadoop classpath. I followed the instruction, and it worked.

I would like to know why hadoop libraries are needed to run spark in standalone or local mode.

Answer (score 1):

Spark uses the Hadoop Configuration class and FileSystem APIs mostly to make it easier for integration with other systems in the Hadoop ecoystem, and not needing to essentially copy all these classes natively into the Spark codebase. In other words, Spark is a data processing framework, not a Filesytem interface or a configuration management library.

When you download the **without-hadoop** version of Spark, that actually implies you already have Hadoop installed and available on the `PATH` & classpath (via `hadoop classpath`). Plus, the Spark download page says "user-provided" Hadoop to make this clear.